# How to write a program in Java that looks for a '00' checking every character in a string?

Tags: java, string, character

I'm trying to write a simple program that asks the user for an input consisting of zeroes and ones and checks every character looking for a double zero '00', if the current character is a '1' the program is considered to be in state "A" and so it prints the state and the character, if the character is a '0' the program is in state "B" and if there's a '00' the program is in state "C", after entering state "C" (after finding a '00') the program can't exit that state,that means that it will keep checking every character,but the resulting string should be "State C" + character even if the character is a single zero or one.

As of now I have something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class onesandzeroes {
     public static void main(String[] args) {     
         System.out.println("Write a String that consists of 0 and 1");
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);
           String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
           
           for (int index = 0; index < inputString.length();
index++) {
     char aChar = inputString.charAt(index);
     if (aChar == '0'){
         System.out.println("State B " + aChar);
         
         /* This is the part I'm having trouble with, I was thinking about something like
         
         if(aChar =='0' && charAt(index + 1 == '0')){
                 System.out.println("State C" + aChar + charAt(index + 1);
                 }
         to look for a '0' that is followed by another '0' but it doesn't work
         */
         
     } else{
         System.out.println("State A " + aChar);
     }
}
    }    
    
}
```

I know that you can probably look the entire string and only check if there's a '00' but I want to check every character individually except when it looks for '00'

So I have 2 questions:
How can I look for a '00' in the string? The ideal way would be to check every '0' for a following '0'.

And how can I make the program print "State C" + character ONLY after the first '00' has been found? that is after the program finds a '00' it should stay in State C for '00' and every other character following it.

Comment: inputString.contains("00") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Write a String that consists of 0 and 1");

        final var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

        var currentState = State.A;

        for (int index = 0; index < inputString.length(); index++) {

            final char currentChar = inputString.charAt(index);

            System.out.println("The current char is " + currentChar + " and I'm in state " + currentState);

            if (currentState == State.C) {
                // do nothing because final state has already been reached
                continue;
            }

            if (currentState == State.B) {
                if (currentChar == '0') {
                    // 2 zeros found got into final state :)
                    currentState = State.C;
                } else {
                    //
                    currentState = State.A;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (currentState == State.A) {
                if (currentChar == '0') {
                    currentState = State.B;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private enum State {
        A, B, C
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate all the answers but yours was the most helpful,I was already thinking about creating a string variable called "state" but your solution is much more elegant,I don't know (yet) what "enum" means so I will look into it now Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can check `inputString.contains("00");`
If true write

```
inputString.charAt(inputString.indexOf("00") + 2);
```